# Time it takes for one train to pass by the front of another

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

Two trains are travelling on parallel tracks, one towards the other. The speed of each is $20m/s$. Train number one is $100m$ long and train number $2$ is $200m$ long.

They meet and pass each other. How long does train $2$ travel past the front of train $1$?

**I got this:**

Because the trains travel at $20m/s$, the result is the same as if one train was going $40m/s$ and the other one wasn't moving.
The train moves for $200m$ to completely pass the front of the other one.
$$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}}$$
$$\text{time}=\frac{\text{length}}{\text{speed}}$$
$$\text{time}=\frac{200m}{40m/s}$$
$$\text{time}=5s$$
This is a problem from a workbook,so I checked the solution.It says $7,5$s.

I think this is actually the time the trains need to pass each other completely.
$$40m/s*7,5s=300m$$
Here $300m$ is the total of both lengths.

Please tell me if I am wrong and if yes what did I miss.

Comment: Looks good! I think the solution in the workbook is wrong for how the problem was posed. Yours looks good!

Comment: I think the problem is in the word "front". If the "front of the train" is just the tip of the locomotive you are right, if the "front" is the front of one side that consists of all carriages then the answer from the book is correct.

Comment: 5 seconds looks right to me. Got the same answer doing it a different way. For the book answer to be right, it should say time to pass the side of train 1 or time to completely clear train 1.